# How to mimic spin button by a label?

Tags: excel, vba

I have two labels on a form

```
lab01_Click:
lab02.Caption = lab02.Caption + 1
```

Is there a way to use lab01 as a spin button ?
If I keep pressing it - then lab02.Caption should keep changing continously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store data in the Tag property also

eg

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
If Label1.Tag = "" Then Label1.Tag = 0
 Label1.Tag = CLng(Label1.Tag) + 1
 Label1.Caption = "Increment: " & Label1.Tag
End Sub

Private Sub Label2_Click()
If Label1.Tag = "" Then Label1.Tag = 0
 Label1.Tag = CLng(Label1.Tag) - 1
 Label1.Caption = "Increment: " & Label1.Tag
End Sub
```

Update: Ok I see you want to keep it incrementing if click is depressed. The only way I can think is a nasty 'hack' which re-triggers a timer event.
You will need to update object names `Userform1` , `Label1` and `Label2` and may need to adjust `Private Declare Function` to `Private Declare PtrSafe Function` for 64bit

Try this in a `MODULE`

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
ByVal uElapse As Long, _
ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" _
(ByVal hWnd As Long, _
ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Private m_TimerID As Long

 'Note:  The duration is measured in milliseconds.
 '         1,000 milliseconds = 1 second
Public Sub StartTimer(ByVal Duration As Long)
     'If the timer isn't already running, start it.
    If m_TimerID = 0 Then
        If Duration > 0 Then
            m_TimerID = SetTimer(0, 0, Duration, AddressOf TimerEvent)
            If m_TimerID = 0 Then
                MsgBox "Timer initialization failed!"
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "The duration must be greater than zero."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Timer already started."
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub StopTimer()
     'If the timer is already running, shut it off.
    If m_TimerID <> 0 Then
        KillTimer 0, m_TimerID
        m_TimerID = 0
    Else
        MsgBox "Timer is not active."
    End If
End Sub

Public Property Get TimerIsActive() As Boolean
     'A non-zero timer ID indicates that it's turned on.
    TimerIsActive = (m_TimerID <> 0)
End Property

Private Sub TimerEvent()
    If UserForm1.Label2.Tag = "" Then UserForm1.Label2.Tag = 0
    UserForm1.Label2.Tag = CLng(UserForm1.Label2.Tag) + 1
    UserForm1.Label2.Caption = "Increment : " & UserForm1.Label2.Tag
End Sub
```

and this in the `USERFORM`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Label1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, _
    ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    StartTimer 200 'millisecond update
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, _
    ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    StopTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: ooo it's ok, but I think it does not resolve the question: I need to mimic a spin button by clicking on lab01. Your code (as mine one also) make only one single change on lab02, and then I must click again and again to reach desired value.